# jquery autocomplete & symfony2

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, autocomplete

So i want to display this list of countries on an input : 
I use Jquery UI Autocomplete with an ajax call to the db.

Javascript :

```
$("#fos_user_registration_form_country").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    scrollHeight: 220, 
       source: function(req, add){
      $.ajax({
            url:Routing.generate('user_register_countries_autocomplete'),
            type:"get",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'title_search='+req.term,
            async: true,
            cache: true,
            success: function(data){
                var suggestions = [];  
                //process response  
                $.each(data, function(i, val){  
                    suggestions.push({"name": val.countryName});  
                });  
                //pass array to callback  
                add(suggestions); 
            }
        });
   }
});
```

Controller :

```
 public function AutoCompletePaysAction()
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyAwesomeWebsiteHomeBundle:Countries');

    $listeCountries = $repository->countriesArray();
    $liste = json_encode($listeCountries);

    return new Response($liste);
}
```

repo

```
public function countriesArray()
    {
        // $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');

        $query = $this->_em->createQuery("SELECT a.countryName FROM MyAwesomeWebsiteHomeBundle:Countries a");
        return $query->getArrayResult();
    }
```

what shows in firebug ( response of my ajax call = all the countries )

```
[{"countryName":"United States"},{"countryName":"Canada"},{"countryName":"Afghanistan"},{"countryName":"Albania"},...
```

-> The ajax call seems to work fine each time i type a letter in the input, but no suggestions appears as it should do with autocomplete.

Also it seems weird to me to make an ajax call each time a letter is typed to retrieve the same values, but well thats how its done in the doc. Also i tried to preload the array but i just can't make it work. tldr : lost.

Any suggestions ? Thanks !

Comment: Normally you would pass whatever the user has typed as a query parameter.  The server would then filter the returned entries based on the parameter.  Presumably each additional letter typed would result in a shorter list of countries.  Hence the "weird" behavior.  It's been too long since I used jquery autocomplete.  Someone else will hopefully point out where you have it configured incorrectly.  It does seem like you would want your action to return a JsonResponse object.

Comment: Indeed replacing json_encode and Response by simply JsonResponse seems to give me a list of choice. ( i can't see , can only see the little dots of the list ) . let's say that's a start

Comment: I think you probably need label in the source supplied.
`suggestions.push({"label": val.countryName});`

Comment: You were both very helpful! Tkanks.
My last problem is how to get this search term into my controller !
I tried a     
$request = $this->get('request');
$search = $request->request->get('title_search');

But var_dump on this shows null.... So basically i have the list of all the countries showing

Comment: You need a value parameter to response data as well.
`suggestions.push({"label": val.countryName, "value": val.countryName});`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything.. I believed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your controller to get the term. Keep in mind that by default autocomplete expects EITHER an array containing single terms. Or and Array of objects with `label` and `value` keys.

```
public function AutoCompletePaysAction(Request $request)
{
    $term = $request->get('term',null)
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyAwesomeWebsiteHomeBundle:Countries');
    if($term){
        $countries = $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->where("c.countryName LIKE '%:term%'")
            ->setParameter('term', $term)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
    else{
        $countries = $repository->findAll();
    }
    $list = array();
    foreach($countries as $country){
        array_push($list, array('label'=>$country->getCountryName(), 'value'=>$country->getCountryName());
    }
    return new JsonResponse($list,200);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i gave up and put all my countries in an html list, i'm quite ashamed but sometimes a man got to do what he's got to do.
Thanks for your help.
And anyway the ajax call is a bit too slow to be interesting, that's my experience.

Comment: In that case, just do what i do and render a js object to the page and use that as the data source so it gives the appearance of search.